# Adapting AppRTC to PeerJs

Tags: android, webrtc, peerjs, apprtc

Hi I m working on Android Native project to connect to Peerjs server . Is there any solution to adapte appRTC(https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo) to connect to my server